# C++ Sentinel/Count Controlled Loop beginning programming

Tags: c++

Hello all this is my first post.  I'm working on a homework assignment with the following parameters.

> Piecework Workers are paid by the piece.  Often worker who produce a
>   greater quantity of output are paid at a higher rate.
>
> ```
> 1 - 199 pieces completed  $0.50 each
> 200 - 399 $0.55 each (for all pieces)
> 400 - 599 $0.60 each
> 600 or more   $0.65 each
> ```
>
> Input: For each worker, input the name and number of pieces completed.
>
> ```
> Name          Pieces
>
> Johnny Begood     265
> Sally Great       650
> Sam Klutz     177
> Pete Precise      400
> Fannie Fantastic  399
> Morrie Mellow     200
> ```
>
> Output: Print an appropriate title and column headings.  There should
>   be one detail line for each worker, which shows the name, number of
>   pieces, and the amount earned.  Compute and print totals of the number
>   of pieces and the dollar amount earned.
>
> Processing: For each person, compute the pay earned by multiplying the
>   number of pieces by the appropriate price.  Accumulate the total
>   number of pieces and the total dollar amount paid.
>
> Sample Program Output:
>
> ```
> Piecework Weekly Report
>
> Name          Pieces  Pay
>
> Johnny Begood     265 145.75
> Sally Great       650 422.50
> Sam Klutz     177 88.5
> Pete Precise      400 240.00
> Fannie Fantastic  399 219.45
> Morrie Mellow     200 110.00
>
> Totals            2091    1226.20
> ```
>
> You are required to code, compile, link, and run a sentinel-controlled
>   loop program that transforms the input to the output specifications as
>   shown in the above attachment.  The input items should be entered into
>   a text file named piecework1.dat and the ouput file stored in
>   piecework1.out . The program filename is piecework1.cpp.  Copies of
>   these three files should be e-mailed to me in their original form.
>
> Read the name using a single variable as opposed to two different
>   variables. To accomplish this, you must use the getline(stream,
>   variable) function as discussed in class, except that you will replace
>   the cin with your textfile stream variable name. Do not forget to code
>   the compiler directive #include < string > at the top of your program
>   to acknowledge the utilization of the string variable, name . Your
>   nested if-else statement, accumulators, count-controlled loop, should
>   be properly designed to process the data correctly.

The code below will run, but does not produce any output.  I think it needs something around line 57 like a count control to stop the loop.

something like (and this is just an example....which is why it is not in the code.)

```
count = 1;
while (count <=4)
```

Can someone review the code and tell me what kind of count I need to introduce, and if there are any other changes that need to be made.

Thanks.

```
//COS 502-90
//November 2, 2012
//This program uses a sentinel-controlled loop that transforms input to output.

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>  //output formatting
#include <string>   //string variables
using namespace std;

int main()
{

double pieces;          //number of pieces made
double rate;            //amout paid per amount produced
double pay;             //amount earned 
string name;            //name of worker
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

//***********input statements****************************
inFile.open("Piecework1.txt");  //opens the input text file
outFile.open("piecework1.out");  //opens the output text file
outFile << setprecision(2) << showpoint;
outFile << name << setw(6) << "Pieces" << setw(12) << "Pay" << endl;
outFile << "_____" << setw(6) << "_____" << setw(12) << "_____" << endl;
getline(inFile, name, '*');         //priming read
inFile >> pieces >> pay >> rate;    // ,,
while (name != "End of File")           //while condition test
{                                   //begining of loop
    pay = pieces * rate;
    getline(inFile, name, '*');     //get next name
    inFile >> pieces;               //get next pieces
}                                   //end of loop
inFile.close();
outFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't produce any output, you mean piecework1.out is empty after running your program?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone review the code and tell me what kind of count I need to introduce, and if there are any other changes that need to be made.

You need statements that direct output to your output file, just as the assignment said to do.  The compiler can't read your mind, and it can't read your homework assignment either. It can only read your code.

You also have a problem with your input statements. The pay rates are not in the input file. All that's in the input file are the workers' names and the number of pieces they produced.